# What is the difference between position relative and absolute (triangle)?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm little surprised while I was creating a triangle using `:after` pseudo class. Why position absolute works fine but not position relative. Look at the below code

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.abs:after {
  position: absolute; /* by changing this value to relative */
  left: -20px;
  top: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="abs">enter your name</div>
</div>
```

[demo with absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/M2qe2/) | [demo with relative](http://jsfiddle.net/M2qe2/1/)

Can anyone picturize the reason for this?

Comment: relative position keeps with the flow of the page.  So naturally, any content added after the text, "enter you name" would display there (eg. content: ".") `enter your name.`  So relative to the position where the period would go, you're giving your box a position 20 pixels to the left of where the period would be (overlapping with the text).  Absolutely positioning the box makes it positioned in a x,y position from the closest relatively positioned containing box (test).  This will be a problem if your input width changes since test contains both your input and your abs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that the technique you're using to create the triangle doesn't work with inline elements, and `:after` pseudo-elements are inline by default. See a test with a simple span: http://jsfiddle.net/YBLpL/.

When you use `position: absolute`, the inline element is considered a block, according to [section 9.7 of the CSS 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

---

Note: although your question seems to be about the meaning of absolute vs. relative, it's actually about the broken shape of the triangle, as you clarified in the comments to the answers (including one deleted answer). You should edit the question to clarify your point.

Answer (score 0):

:after psudo class adds the content after the content of .abs div but is a child of the .abs div. That would explain the relative and absolute behavior of the inserted content.

When you make the inserted content position relative then it's supposed to be after the original content i.e. "enter your name" as it's part of the visual flow. whereas if you make this absolute, it's removed from the visual flow and so it positioned in the beginning or as per left, right values with respect to the parent .abs div.

Comment: can you picturize why the relative is creating the points of triangle is showing so?

Comment: @C-Link Hm, there's more to it than I thought. Will look into it.

Comment: @C-Link It seems to be related to the pseudo-element being inline. `position:absolute` forces it to be interpreted as a block (apparently for certains purposes only). See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: yes seems like inline elements have default height and you cannot set it to 0. @bfavaretto is right pseudo element is set as inline and the cropped left part you see is because of the default height and so is the gap between top and bottom border.